# SQL group by and order by issue

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a table - tasks - with the following data:

```
task    user     when_added
---------------------------
run     1        2012-08-09
walk    2        2012-08-07
bike    2        2012-08-07
car     1        2012-08-06
run     2        2012-08-06
car     1        2012-08-05
bike    1        2012-08-04
run     1        2012-08-04
```

As you can see the task is repetitive.

Question is, when i show the data e.g.

```
select * from tasks group by task order by when_added desc
```

How does the group by affecting the results? Does 'group by' group them in any order, can I make it?

The reason i ask is that I have a large table which i show data as above and if I lose the group by and just show results in date order, I get some results which do not show on group by, which means the task has been done before but it seems to be grouping by the oldest date and i want the newest date at the top of the pile.

Hope this makes sense...is it possible to affect the group by order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
select task, group_concat(user), max(when_added)
from tasks 
group by task
order by when_added desc
```

`group by` is an aggregate function. In MySQL you can select not aggregates columns anyway, but you should not do that.

If you group by a column then the results will be distinct for that column and all other data will be grouped around it. So there might be multiple data where `task` is `run` for instance.  Just selecting other columns will select a random result. You should pick a specific result from that group like `max` or `min` or `sum` or concatenate them.

Comment: Many thanks! That kind of works... well it does work apart from the user field is a mass string of the same user_id for each time they have performed the task, and I need that to be a singular user_id so I can pull the user details with a join from another table

Comment: fixed - just call user twice - so, select task, group_concat(user) as wrong, user as correct, max(when_added)

Comment: And what user should it be? Just any?

Comment: In fact disregard that whole comment I made, I'm already getting the info in a join! Doh! Anyway, many thanks for your help, it's appreciated.